# ReferenceError: window is not defined w/ useMedia() hook + next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

Because I am using next.js I think I'm getting a "window is not defined" error due to code executing on the server side rather than on the client. I tried using useLayoutEffect() to wait for the page to render but it still didn't work. Is there anything I can do to change the custom useMedia() hook below to fix this issue?

```
export default (queries, values, defaultValue) => {
  const mediaQueryLists = queries.map(q => window.matchMedia(q));

  const getValue = () => {
    const index = mediaQueryLists.findIndex(mql => mql.matches);

    return typeof values[index] !== "undefined" ? values[index] : defaultValue;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(getValue);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => setValue(getValue);

    mediaQueryLists.forEach(mql => mql.addListener(handler));

    return () => mediaQueryLists.forEach(mql => mql.removeListener(handler));
  }, []);

  return value;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the window doesn't mount on time try to wait for it using:

```
let mediaQueryLists
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  mediaQueryLists = queries.map(q => window.matchMedia(q));
} else {
  mediaQueryLists = []
}
```